# Range concatenation grammars which are unambiguous as (and are NOT CFL)?

Tags: fl.formal-languages

Are there any range concatenation grammars that

1. generate only one possible parse tree
2. are not also context-free?

Comment: Write a grammar for $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n>0\}$.  Chances are it will be unambiguous.